# HASP dongle in kvm?

Tags: windows-7, usb, ubuntu-10.04, dongle, linux-kvm

Is there a way to use a HASP dongle (Aladdin) in a kvm virtual machine (guest) running Windows 7 professional with Ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10 as host?

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple of different options to get USB into KVM.  KVM does allow for you to map a USB port into the VM.  There is a basic tutorial [here](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB).  You will need to try this out, I have never had much success for non hard drives keyboards and mice.

Your other solution is using [usb over ethernet](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=usb+over+ethernet).  You install a driver on another machine (server) where you will install the dongel, and then on the KVM VM (client) install a driver as well.  There are many companies that do this, and I have had good success with several.  (Especially with printer / scanner boxes)  I have used dedicated hardware by [digi](http://www.digi.com/products/usb/anywhereusb.jsp) in a VMWare environment and had no problems.  This is nice in that you don't need to have another machine turned on etc.

For software there are several options.  Most have a try and then buy model.  I would try out [eltima](http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/) as they specifically list Ubuntu and windows-7 as tested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. 
Even though I am on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS at the time of writing (2019) this, I think it is the same with Win 7. We are using eToken (Aladdin kknowledge systems) issued by Sectigo for code signing on a virtualised build system running Jenkins.

1. **Do *not* use Remote desktop.** If you are connected with RDP, install VNC and reboot. It seems, that remote disconnects eToken as explained in "Build server" [section here](https://xrstf.de/2018/03/safenet-token-code-signing-gitlab-ci/).
2. Install Gemalto SafeNet Authentication client, it installs drivers for eToken
3. Shut down virtual machine
4. Connect eToken to virtual machine with virt-manger and add **USB Host device**
   [Connect USB host device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ctx4.png)
5. Start virtual machine again and **connect to it with VNC**. If you right click on SafeNet authenticatino client you should see it is connected
6. Enable single login in advanced settings of SafeNet Authenticatin client, so you don't have login to eToken every time you sign your code or you have automated build system.
   [Enable single login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keqmZ.png)